# view multiple log file in a single terminal

Tags: linux, shell

I am running a batch job daily which runs on different machines daily (Say like 4 machines). Each machine has its own log file logging all the details. Is it possible to create a shell script to split the window and run tail command to view all the log files in a single terminal?

Answer (score 1):

There's a utility that does that already: [`multitail`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/).

It splits your terminal into as many regions as files you're monitoring. Runs on must Unix-like OSes, and the docs says it can run on Windows with Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Putty then try to use Putty Connection Manager to view multiple terminals in a single window.
Programatically i am not sure you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `terminator` - http://www.tenshu.net/terminator/

Terminator lets your arrange terminal windows in a grid, so you can have a 2x2 grid with 4 windows running tail for each log file.

```
sudo aptitude install terminator
```